# Changing the value of a variable in a function and using it in outside the scoop

Tags: c#, function, class, oop

I need to declare 3 variables in a class ,and creat a funtion to assign these variables to other values ,and creat another function to calculate the distance The new values are unreachable ,and my Changed(X/Y/Z) are always zero

```
class Point3D
{
    public double x, y, z, ChangedX = 0, ChangedY = 0, ChangedZ = 0;

    public void MoveTo(double NewX, double NewY, double NewZ)
    {

        x = NewX;
        NewX = ChangedX;
        y = NewY;
        NewY = ChangedY;
        z = NewZ;
        NewZ = ChangedZ;

    }

    public double DistanceTo()
    {
       double DeltaX = Math.Pow((ChangedX - x), 2);
       double DeltaY = Math.Pow((ChangedY - y), 2);
       double DeltaZ = Math.Pow((ChangedZ - z), 2);

       return Math.Sqrt(DeltaX + DeltaY + DeltaZ);

    }
```

Also, I've started studying OOP not a long while ago
Are there any resources of courses that you recommend that may help me?

Comment: In your posted code, there is nothing that modifies your ChangedX/Y/Z variables after init them to 0. Do you set them from outside the class, in some other code?

Comment: what is your purpose of assigning ChangedX/Y/Z into NewX/Y/Z ? Since you are not calling by reference, those values will be lost when MoveTo() scope ends.

Comment: If the variables are not reachable it means that you have more than one instance of the class.  To share variables in a class you need to use the same instance of the class or make the variables static so they are always the same in every instance of the class.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is how can I declare 3 variables, changing their values in a function ,and then using both the orignal&new values in another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood the intention of your code, that is what I would do in your case:

```
internal class Point3D
{
    public double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, PreviousX, PreviousY, PreviousZ;

    public void MoveTo(double NewX, double NewY, double NewZ)
    {

        PreviousX = x; // remember previous value to use in delta calculation
        x = NewX;

        PreviousY = y;
        y = NewY;

        PreviousZ = z;
        z = NewZ;

    }

    public double DistanceTo()
    {
        double DeltaX = Math.Pow((x - PreviousX), 2);
        double DeltaY = Math.Pow((y - PreviousY), 2);
        double DeltaZ = Math.Pow((z - PreviousZ), 2);

        return Math.Sqrt(DeltaX + DeltaY + DeltaZ);

    }
}
```

As to courses recommendation, when you start it's always good to see some video courses at the beginning, for example https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/object-oriented-programming-fundamentals-csharp (you can see this course at their site, or search the web).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much